# How can I compile a file written in Assembly 8086 in DOSBox (on MacBook M2)?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I don't know how to compile an .asm file written with Assembly 8086 on MacOS with M2.

I tried to install DosBox, I get to `cd name folder` where I have the .asm file, but typing `tasm filename.asm` gives me the error "*Illegal command: tasm*" and I can't go on. If anyone knows if there is a way I will thank them.

Comment: Borland Turbo Assembler was commercial software, so it's not supplied with DosBox.  Before proceeding, are you sure that the code you are trying to assemble was written for TASM?  There are many different incompatible dialects of 8086 assembly.

Comment: You would have to download TASM and install it from disk image. Winworld maintains a copy of such a disk image here: https://winworldpc.com/product/turbo-assembler/20 . If you showed your code we'd be able to tell you if it is even MASM/TASM code or something like NASM.

Comment: If you want to use free open-source tools, NASM should work in DOSBox.  As a bonus, you can run NASM natively on your Mac (still producing an x86-16 flat binary with the default `nasm -fbin` option), so you can edit/assemble outside of DOSBox if that's more convenient, only needing to run/debug inside.  (Especially if you make a `.com` executable directly, instead of needing to also link after assembling.)

Answer (score 0):

Assembler isn't installed by default. You need to download tasm/masm binaries and place them in directory you're working in.